# Seeing prompt when tying to install Ubuntu 14.04 from USB

Tags: command-line, startup

On my HP Mini.
I had installed Lubuntu,unsuccessfully, so nolonger have windows.
Now want to install Ubuntu 14.04.3 32 bits but:

Trying to install Ubuntu 14.04 from USB, once booted and install is clicked all I see is a prompt on the screen.

Is a command required to continue process?

Comment: And what is this prompt?

Comment: No, it shouldn't. Could you post a screenshot of the prompt you see? Or report the text manually, but a screenshot should be easier.

Comment: kos, thank you for your answer but I can't screenshot.  All I have on that screen is a lite screen with a flashing prompt waaiting for a command!